# could not find connection string in entityframework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i am creating an n-tier c# console application where 
1. Data
2. DataAccess
3. BusinessLogic and
4. Client

those are all c# console projects. 
i have created the edmx data model and the context class in data layer 
and then access these objects into Dataaccess then Business logic and finnally on client .
But when an entity going from client to datalayer for crud the context connection on data layer. says that 'connection name Entities could not found in the application config' , although in data layer app.config i have the connection string name for the edmx file. and when i individually run the data layer console it works fine.
why is the error?

Comment: Are you copying the app.config or the MyDataLayerApp.exe.config file, you need the latter not the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the config file must be in the project which is run. So you have to put it in the Client

Comment: Yes. copy your connection string which named as "Entities" to your startup console application. ( I think you are starting "Client" console application first. )

Comment: but why it will not work when it is already in data layer ? because i created context on data layer.

Comment: If you want to have the configuration in config file, it must be the config file of the start up project. It is like that. If you want to avoid that (I fully understand the desire) set the configuration by code in the library project.

Answer (score 0):

Connection string should also be in your main project also it would not work if it is only in project library which you are referring.. please copy this connection string and paste it to your main project's "Web.config or App.config(whichever is applicable)".